# Get only Methods with specific signature out of Type.GetMethods()

Tags: c#

I want to list all methods of a type with a specific method signature.

For example, if a type has a few public methods:

```
public void meth1 (int i);
public void meth2 (int i, string s);
public void meth3 (int i, string s);
public int meth4 (int i, string s);
```

I want to list all the methods which expect an int as first and a string as second parameter and returns void.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetMethodsBySig(this Type type, Type returnType, params Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        return type.GetMethods().Where((m) =>
        {
            if (m.ReturnType != returnType) return false;
            var parameters = m.GetParameters();
            if ((parameterTypes == null || parameterTypes.Length == 0))
                return parameters.Length == 0;
            if (parameters.Length != parameterTypes.Length)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (parameters[i].ParameterType != parameterTypes[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var methods =  this.GetType().GetMethodsBySig(typeof(void), typeof(int), typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
type.GetMethods().Where(p =>
                p.GetParameters().Select(q => q.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) }) &&
                p.ReturnType == typeof(void)
            );
```

Comment: er... my answer was LINQ, just a slightly different syntax.

Comment: ok - more linqified... making use of sequence equal rather than writing it as a lamba... I will change the comment.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to inspect all `MethodInfo`s yourself. By calling `MethodInfo.GetParameters()` you'll get a collection of `ParameterInfo` objects, which in turn have a property `ParameterType`.

The same for the return type: inspect the `ReturnType` property of `MethodInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

Given this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void M1(int i){}
    public void M2(int i, string s){}
    public void M3(int i, string s){}
    public int M4(int i, string s){ return 0; }
}
```

A bit of Reflection and LINQ can be used:

```
Type t = typeof (Foo);
var theMethods = t.GetMethods().Where(mi =>
                            {
                                var p = mi.GetParameters();
                                if (p.Length != 2)
                                    return false;

                                if (p[0].ParameterType != typeof(int) 
                                     || p[1].ParameterType != typeof(string))
                                    return false;

                                return mi.ReturnType == typeof (void);
                            });
```

or the other syntax (which is actually nicer in this case)

```
var theMethods = from mi in t.GetMethods()
                    let p = mi.GetParameters()
                    where p.Length == 2
                        && p[0].ParameterType == typeof (int)
                        && p[1].ParameterType == typeof (string)
                        && mi.ReturnType == typeof (void)
                    select mi;
```

Test:

```
foreach (var methodInfo in theMethods)
{
    Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
}
```

Output:

```
M2
M3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the extension method to use improved from EvgK's answer.

```
 private static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetMethodsBySig(this Type type,
                                                                Type returnType,
                                                                Type customAttributeType,
                                                                bool matchParameterInheritence,
                                                                params Type[] parameterTypes)
        {
            return type.GetMethods().Where((m) =>
            {
                if (m.ReturnType != returnType) return false;

            if ((customAttributeType != null) && (m.GetCustomAttributes(customAttributeType, true).Any() == false))
                return false;

            var parameters = m.GetParameters();

            if ((parameterTypes == null || parameterTypes.Length == 0))
                return parameters.Length == 0;

            if (parameters.Length != parameterTypes.Length)
                return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (((parameters[i].ParameterType == parameterTypes[i]) ||
                (matchParameterInheritence && parameterTypes[i].IsAssignableFrom(parameters[i].ParameterType))) == false)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
```

Use it like

```
var methods = SomeTypeToScan.GetMethodsBySig(
                typeof(SomeReturnType),
                typeof(SomeSpecialAttributeMarkerType),
                true, 
                typeof(SomeParameterType))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: you don't need to "litter" this with attribute - you can just chain a where after that for more granular control - but yes, assignable from is excellent - and that should also be used inversely on return type meaning requestedReturnType.AssignableFrom(methodReturnType); - there's also a step further - a signature builder to accomodate in / out direction ;)