# C# - Passing all the method arguments to another method?

Tags: c#, oop

I've got a class, which has three overloaded methods. Let's say, there is:

```
class MyChildClass
{
    public void myMethod(int i)
        { /* do something with i */ }
    public void myMethod(int a, string b)
        { /* get i from a and b and call: */ myMethod(i); }
    public void myMethod(string c, string d)
        { /* get i from c and d and call: */ myMethod(i); }
}
```

Now I'd like this class to be a private field in other (parent) class, but I need those three methods to be accessible. For now, I just did:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    private MyChildClass myObject = new myChildClass(); // or similar
    public void myMethod(int i) 
        { myObject.myMethod(i);    }
    public void myMethod(int a, string b) 
        { myObject.myMethod(a, b); }
    public void myMethod(string c, string s) 
        { myObject.myMethod(c, d); }
}
```

Is there a way to implement it as one short method? Something which would look like:

```
public void myMethod(unknownListOfArgumentsOfDifferentTypes args)
    { myObject.myMethod(args); }
```

I tried to use `public void myMethod(params object[] something)` but it didn't work. Is it possible, or do I have to "project" every method into another?

**EDIT:** Child class has various methods and fields, which I want to be accessible for parent class only. That's why I don't want parent to derive after it. I didn't explain that, sorry if it looked like child class contains only those three methods. Those are the methods I want to be accessible as public methods of parent class.

Comment: Don't. When you write such code a kitten dies.

Comment: You have to do it like you are already doing.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5511/Dynamic-Proxy-Creation-Using-C-Emit might point you in the right direction

Comment: I've done editing my answer now, probably.

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  If you ever add parameters to the parent class, you could easily forget to implement those parameters in the child classes.  Effectively you are going from strong typed parameters to loose. The best part about strong types is that if stuff changes (naming, types, etc...), the project won't build unless you update the usages. If you do this, the project will build and you will be none the wiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `public void myMethod(params object[] something)` as in:

```
public static void Main()
{
    UnknownArgumentsMethod1(1, 2, 3, "foo");
}

public static void UnknownArgumentsMethod1(params object[] list)
{
    UnknownArgumentsMethod2(list);
}

public static void UnknownArgumentsMethod2(params object[] list)
{
    foreach (object o in list)
    {
        if (o.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is an integer: " + (int)o);
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a string: " + (string)o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I marked it as an answer, because it's the closest to what I wanted to achieve. Unfortunately, looking at the code, I think using one method in parent for every one method in child is less complicated and should be faster than checking parameters' type inside the new "universal" method. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: It should be faster, but more cumbersome in case you have a lot of methods where you want to pass the arguments received.

Comment: @WRonX, what would happen when several methods have the same signature and differ only by name?

Comment: Let's give this code a minute of silence. Why on earth would you want to pass an array (of unknown size) of objects, check its size, cast all items and then dispatch the call to an appropriate method? Would it really not be easier to write a couple of readable lines of code (even seemingly redundant code) than use this monstrosity? You have such a beautiful, strongly typed language at your disposal and you're turning it into an uglier brother of PHP. Shame on you, guys. Shame on you.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna, absolutely. This would create a lot of confusion in production code. But the OP seemed to have wanted it, so...

Comment: @sohil I guess it's just one of those questions... Your answer is obviously correct in terms of OP's requirements, but there's a little chance you would write such code knowing that your supervisor is going to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do

```
class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
}
```

same effect, less code, and this way `MyChildClass` is a `MyBaseClass`

---

If you implement some sort of generic facade using reflection you'll just be reducing performance, bypassing the benefits of type safety and delaying the discovery of problems.

You'll also have have a "has a" relationship instead "is a" relationship which is incongruent with your class names.

---

If you want to give up this simplicty with its associated benefits you could make use the [`GetMethodBySig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5152539/659190) extension accepted in this post.

Something like this,

```
class SemiGenericFacade<T> where T : new()
{
    private readonly t = new T();

    public void CallVoidOnT(string name, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var paramTypes = parameters.Select(p => typeof(p))

        var match = typeof(T).GetMethodBySig(typeof(void), paramTypes)
            .Single(mi => mi.Name == name);

        match.Invoke(this.t, parameters);
    }
}
```

Following on from Piotr Justyna's comment, implementing and using this method results in the cat turning into a tiger and eating her kittens.

---

If you were to do this it would make sense to add to the linked extension

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static MethodInfo GetMethodByNameThenSig(
        this Type type,
        string name, 
        Type returnType, 
        params Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        return type.GetMethods().Where((m) =>
        {
            if (m.Name != name)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (m.ReturnType != returnType)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var parameters = m.GetParameters();
            if ((parameterTypes == null || parameterTypes.Length == 0))
            {
                return parameters.Length == 0;
            }

            if (parameters.Length != parameterTypes.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (parameters[i].ParameterType != parameterTypes[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }).Single();
    }
}
```

Which you could use like this,

```
class GenericFacade<T> where T : new()
{
    private readonly t = new T();

    public void CallOnInternal(string name, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var paramTypes = parameters.Select(p => typeof(p))

        var match = typeof(T).GetMethodByNameThenSig(
            name,
            typeof(void),
            paramTypes);

        match.Invoke(this.t, parameters);
    }

    public TResult CallOnInternal<TResult>(string name, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var paramTypes = parameters.Select(p => typeof(p))

        var match = typeof(T).GetMethodByNameThenSig(
            name,
            typeof(TResult),
            paramTypes);

        return (TResult)match.Invoke(this.t, parameters);
    }
}
```

---

**FINAL EDIT**

Looking at the code involved to use reflection and considering the cost associated with the loss of type safety. I'd suggest its better to establish the "has-a" relationship explicitly in the traditional manner.

Comment: Have do you know that what ever is modelled with MyChildClass is indeed a MyBaseClass?
If I had a class `style` with a BAckgroundColor property and a class `TextArea` and wanted to expose a BackgroundColor property and internally in TextArea I kept the style as a filed of type `style` then simply deriving TextArea from style would be less than ideal

Comment: @RuneFS sounds like a different question.

Comment: @RuneFS: you're right here, I want to fully use the child class object's features only inside parent class, and make publicly available only some selected methods of it. I already edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jodrell I'm sure it sounds like a different question to you since your answer does fit the way I read the question. However there's no support in the question for a is-a relation ship aside from perhaps arbitrary names. Inheritance is often misused. It should only be used when there's an established is-a relationship. Which is this case there's not.

Comment: @RuneFS and all the members of `MyBaseClass` are exposed. Semantics aside, thats the salient point. Either way, my answer covers both aspects of the question now.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be to have inheritance.

In your case (even though the names of the classes suggest otherwise) the way to do it is by inheriting the ChildClass in the BaseClass and that way you would have the methods from the ChildClass exposed through the BaseClass.

ex:

```
class MyBaseClass: MyChildClass
{
}
```

If the classes are not related and you just want to have an instance of MyChildClass in MyBaseClass but only expose a certain set of methods but by not making the others private what you could do is expose the MyChildClass instance through an interface that only exposes the necessary fields like so:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public  IChildClass ChildClassInstance = new ChildClass();
}

public class ChildClass : IChildClass
{
    public void myMethod(int i)
    { /* do something with i */ }
    public void myMethod(int a, string b)
    { /* get i from a and b and call: */ myMethod(i); }
    public void myMethod(string c, string d)
    { /* get i from c and d and call: */ myMethod(i); }
}

public interface IChildClass
{
    void myMethod(int i);
    void myMethod(int a, string b);
}
```

and then you could access only the methods that you allow to be exposed through an instance of the base class:

```
BaseClass test = new BaseClass();
test.ChildClassInstance.myMethod(1);
test.ChildClassInstance.myMethod(1,"test");
```