# AmbiguousMatchException thrown

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i wrote this code:

```
 MethodInfo method2 = typeof(IntPtr).GetMethod(
            "op_Explicit",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            new Type[]{
        typeof(IntPtr),

        },
            null

            );
```

if I try to run i get an ambiguousmatchexception, how can i solve this problem? thanks

The method i am trying to get is op_Explicit(intptr) return value int32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standart overloads for choosing between methods with different types. You must find method by yourself. You can write your own extension methods, like this:

```
public static class TypeExtensions {
    public static MethodInfo GetMethod(this Type type, string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Type[] types, Type returnType ) {
        var methods = type
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(mi => mi.Name == "op_Explicit")
            .Where(mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(int));

        if (!methods.Any())
            return null;

        if (methods.Count() > 1)
            throw new System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException();


        return methods.First();
    }

    public static MethodInfo GetExplicitCastToMethod(this Type type, Type returnType ) 
    {
        return type.GetMethod("op_Explicit", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, new Type[] { type }, returnType);
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
MethodInfo m = typeof(IntPtr).GetExplicitCastToMethod(typeof(int));
```

Be accurately, there are two defined casts in IntPtr class:

```
public static explicit operator IntPtr(long value)
public static explicit operator long(IntPtr value)
```

And no defined casts in System.Int64 class (long is alias of Int64).

You can use `Convert.ChangeType` for this purposes

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but why it gives me errorr on .Where?
it also gives error on   return type.GetMethod("op_Explicit", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, new Type[] { type }, returnType);

Comment: import System.Reflection with `using System.Reflection` in start of your file

Comment: Ok all error fixed except this  return type.GetMethod("op_Explicit", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, new Type[] { type }, returnType);

It says no overload of the method Getmethod accept 4 arguments

Comment: @user1872492 I defined this overload of GetMehod in my TypeExtensions, have you used it?

Comment: Lol. Here it works: http://ideone.com/9Gqvbz. Please, paste your code somewhere (pastebin) and show compiler errors log

Comment: quote: " It says no overload of the method Getmethod accept". You writed Getmethod, but I named it as GetMethod. Maybe problem here?

Comment: I Controlled and the name is ok GetMethod, i only wrote wrong here :(

Comment: @user1872492 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33189/discussion-between-nsinreal-and-user1872492)

Comment: i am in chat now sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple explicit operators which allow `IntPtr` as a parameter and they differ only with their return types. Try to use the solution from this question to get the method which you're interested in by specifying not only parameter types but also return type:

[Get only Methods with specific signature out of Type.GetMethods()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152346/get-only-methods-with-specific-signature-out-of-type-getmethods)