# Call a method passed as parameter on an object passed as parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, func

I have a class defining several functions with the same signature

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyParam1() ...
    public string MyParam2() ...
    ...
}
```

From another class I want to call a method passed as parameter on an object passed as parameter

```
void MyFunction(MyClass anObject, Func<string> aMethod)
{
    string val = ??? // Here call aMethod on anObject
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible to do this using reflection, but is there a not to difficult way to do it ?

In fact I have a set of objects, not a single object, it's why I cannot call directly the method of the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only Methods with specific signature out of Type.GetMethods()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152346/get-only-methods-with-specific-signature-out-of-type-getmethods)

Comment: It isn't altogether clear what you're asking here. A delegate already knows which instance it is supposed to be called on. You can call your `MyFunction` like this: `MyFunction(someObject, () => "test");` in which case the passed delegate is not from or on `someObject`, what would you expect to happen here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to make the question as simple as possible and I missed to point out one difficulty. In fact my first parameter is a set of objects and I want to call the same method on each object.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass the instance method as a function, **it is already bound to the instance**, so your `anObject` is useless in this case.

This code already operates on `this`:

```
MyFunction(null, this.DoSomething);
```

Here `val` will always be the result of `this.DoSomething` in the context of the caller:

```
string val = aMethod();
```

What you can do instead of passing the instance method around, is create a static method that has a parameter for `anObject`. In that way, your static method can do instance specific tasks.

```
public string MyParam2(MyClass instance) { }

void MyFunction(MyClass anObject, Func<MyClass, string> aMethod)
{
    string val = aMethod(anObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about `anObject` as `aMethod` **is already bound to an instance**.  The definition of a delegate is that it's a [**reference** to an **instance** of a method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

Therefore the following should suffice:

```
void MyFunction(Func<string> aMethod)
{
    string val = aMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to call a given method on a object, the don't use `Func` but pass in the object and the name of the method:

```
class Test
{
    public static void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var t = new Test();
    var methodInfo = t.GetType().GetMethod("SayHello");
    methodInfo.Invoke(t, null);

}
```

When executed, this will print

```
Hello
```

as it will call the `SayHello` method on the `Test` instance `t`.